# HDMI 1920x1080 cut off screen

Tags: screen, hdmi

I have my PC plugged into a 1920x1080 TV with an HDMI cable. The problem is is that lots of my screen has been cut off like the panel at the side and the shutdown area. I have checked in the settings that it is definitely at 1920x1080 and does not give me an option to go higher. I am running on the intel 4000 graphics on an asus p8z77 i deluxe board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set up the screen size and position offsets on the television.  This is normally buried in the screen configuration menus somewhere.  The may be an auto configure in there, same as there is for a monitor.

The reasons are the same as they are for a computer monitor - differences in sync and refresh timings.

Comment: OK then I will try that and see how it goes.

Comment: @KieranMarriott In particular look for a setting called "Overscan" and turn it off.

Comment: My tv actually had a setting called "computer" or something similar which worked well.